# Video encryption and decryption in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, encryption

I am developing a mobile app with Cordova. I have downloaded the video and store it in the client device.

I need to store an encrypted video file so that client can't circulate the video. While the user is playing the video, the app should decrypt the video on the fly. These files are big, so is there a way to encrypt the file in a chunks, like YouTube has done, and decrypt accordingly?

```
var videocreateFileSource1 = offlineRootDirectory+"/video/sess12.mp4";
var inputUri=encodeURI("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb.mp4");
var outputPath = videocreateFileSource1;
fileTransfer.onprogress = function(result){
var percent =  result.loaded / result.total * 100;
percent = Math.round(percent);
console.log('Downloaded:  ' + percent + '%'); 
}; 
                                                                    };
fileTransfer.download(
                 inputUri,
                 outputPath,
                 function (entry) {
                                   console.log("completed the video and store into device");
                                  },
                  function (error) {
                                   console.log("download error: source=" + error.source + ", target=" + error.target + ", error code=" + error.code);
                  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question a bit. To get a good response here, it is best to show what you have tried - or at least tell us what you've tried and what the results were. You can [edit] these into your question.

Comment: Remember, encrypting the file will only keep it safe from amateurs - if people insist in distributing it, they _will_ find a way to get the file from the device after it is decrypted. Or they'll find the decryption key, whether in your app or when it is sent to the app.

Comment: that is different case but YouTube did this so i belive there is a way . so right now i need to encrypt the video on the fly so that atleast some user can't access, exception is always there for them i will find the way. or if you have any alternate idea to avoid the circulation of video then plz let me know.

Comment: i am also stuck with this problem